# save copy of mail that i send lotus notes (using script)

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

**Question:**

1. How to save a copy of mail that i send using lotus notes (if using
   script)
2. Do i need to copy maildoc, using copyallitem and then put it
       inside the folder (send mail).

Below is my sample agent i write of sending mail, but i have problem to make a copy of sent mail!

```
Option Public

Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
Dim stream As NotesStream
Sub Initialize
    Dim ss As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim vw As NotesView
    Dim maildb As NotesDatabase

    Dim ec As NotesViewEntryCollection
    Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
    Dim doc As NotesDocument

    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity, header As NotesMIMEHeader, stream As NotesStream
    Dim child As NotesMIMEEntity

'   Dim nam As NotesName
'   Dim principal As String

'   Set nam = ss.CreateName("LSBS Admin")
'   principal = nam.Common

    email$="TestUser1@devsvr1.pcs.com.my"

    Dim rtBody As NotesRichTextItem

    Set db=ss.Currentdatabase
    Set vw=db.getview("(test send mail)")

    Set maildb = ss.getdatabase (db.server, "mail.box") 'Get Mailbox on server

    Set ec = vw.Allentries
    Set entry=ec.getfirstentry

    Do While Not entry Is Nothing
        Set doc = entry.Document
        Set stream = ss.Createstream()
        ss.Convertmime = False
        Set maildoc = maildb.Createdocument()

        maildoc.Form = "Memo"
        maildoc.Principal = "LSBSAdmin@surveyboardsarawak.com"  'principal

        maildoc.SendTo = email$
        maildoc.Recipients = maildoc.sendto

        Set body = maildoc.Createmimeentity

        Set header = body.Createheader("Subject")   '   subject
        Call header.Setheaderval("Test send mail to folder")


        Call stream.Writetext(|<html><body>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<b>Dear Sir,</b><br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<p> Thank you </p>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<p> </p>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|Secretary<br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|Land Surveyors Board Sarawak<br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<em>(No signature is required on this computer generated document)</em><br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|</body></html>|)
        Set child = body.Createchildentity()    'insert the email content
        Call child.Setcontentfromtext(stream, "text/HTML;charset=iso-8859-1", ENC_NONE)
        Call stream.Close()
        Call stream.Truncate()
%rem        
        Set child = body.Createchildentity()    'attach the excel into the email
        Set header = child.Createheader("Content-Type")
        Call header.Setheaderval("multipart/mixed")
        Set header = child.Createheader("Content-Disposition")
        Call header.Setheaderval(|attachment; filename="| + xlfilename + |"|)
        Set header = child.Createheader("Content-ID")
        Call header.Setheaderval(|"| + xlfilename + |"|)
        Set stream = ss.Createstream()

        Call child.Setcontentfrombytes(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
        Call stream.Close()
        Call stream.Truncate()
%end rem        
        Call maildoc.save(False,False) '    send mail
    '   Call maildoc.Send(False)
        ss.Convertmime = True   

        Set entry = ec.Getnextentry(entry)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Attach photo is result of mail

[image: want to store fake user]

I using Basic Notes
Click File > Preferences > User Preferences.

Under Sending, click one of the options in the Save copies of messages that I send field.
Always - to save all messages you send in the Sent view.
Never - never save messages you send in the Sent view
Ask me - get prompted to save each message you send when you send it. If you click Yes when asked to save a message, the message is saved in the Sent view

Setting doesn't help me save the email that i sent.

**Coding updated as suggestion, i might forgot some part of the code, if possible can you point me which part is wrong. Thanks**

```
Option Public

Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
Dim stream As NotesStream
Sub Initialize
    Dim ss As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim vw As NotesView
    Dim maildb As NotesDatabase

    Dim ec As NotesViewEntryCollection
    Dim entry As NotesViewEntry
    Dim doc As NotesDocument

    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity, header As NotesMIMEHeader, stream As NotesStream
    Dim child As NotesMIMEEntity


    email$="TestUser1@devsvr1.pcs.com.my"

    Dim rtBody As NotesRichTextItem

    Set db=ss.Currentdatabase
    Set vw=db.getview("(test send mail)")

    Set maildb = New NotesDatabase( "" , "" )
    Call maildb.openMail()

    Set ec = vw.Allentries
    Set entry=ec.getfirstentry

    Do While Not entry Is Nothing
        Set doc = entry.Document
        Set stream = ss.Createstream()
        ss.Convertmime = False
        Set maildoc = maildb.Createdocument()

        maildoc.Form = "Memo"

        maildoc.From = "LSBSAdmin@somedomain.com@surveyboardsarawak.com"  'from
        maildoc.Principal = "LSBSAdmin@somedomain.com@surveyboardsarawak.com"  'principal

        maildoc.SendTo = email$
        maildoc.Recipients = maildoc.sendto

        Set body = maildoc.Createmimeentity

        Set header = body.Createheader("Subject")   '   subject
        Call header.Setheaderval("Test send mail to folder")


        Call stream.Writetext(|<html><body>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<b>Dear Sir,</b><br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<p> Thank you </p>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<p> </p>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|Secretary<br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|Land Surveyors Board Sarawak<br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|<em>(No signature is required on this computer generated document)</em><br>|)
        Call stream.Writetext(|</body></html>|)
        Set child = body.Createchildentity()    'insert the email content
        Call child.Setcontentfromtext(stream, "text/HTML;charset=iso-8859-1", ENC_NONE)
        Call stream.Close()
        Call stream.Truncate()

        maildoc.SaveMessageOnSend = True
        Call maildoc.Send(False)

        ss.Convertmime = True   

        Set entry = ec.Getnextentry(entry)
    Loop

End Sub
```

[image: new result]

Agent signer is devadmin, which i don want let user know is this user send out the email

[image: agent signer]

**Attached photo for domain**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating the message in mail.box in order to spoof the From header (without using Principal, which triggers the router to treat the message as "sent on behalf of"). you will need to copy the message to the sender's mail database. The [NotesDocument.CopyToDatabase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_COPYTODATABASE_METHOD.html) method is the simplest way to do this.

There is, however, no such thing as the "Sent folder". It is a view, so you can't use NotesDocument.PutInFolder(). Instead, you have to make the document fit the criteria in the selection formula for the Sent folder. If you look at that formula in Domino Designer (I'm not reproducing it here because I *want* you to do that!), you will see that it depends on the existence of a PostedDate field, so you will need to add few lines of code to create a NotesDateTime and set it as the value of the PostedDate item before you call CopyToDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

You create your mail in the mail.box of the server, not in your personal mailfile. Therefor you don't see them. None of the preferences has any effect on mails that are created programmatically.

replace

```
Set maildb = ss.getdatabase (db.server, "mail.box") 'Get Mailbox on server
```

with

```
Set maildb = New NotesDatabase( "" , "" )
Call maildb.openMail()
```

And

```
Call maildoc.save(False,False) '    send mail
```

with

```
maildoc.SaveMessageOnSend = true
Call maildoc.Send(False)
```

As you try to "fake" the sender of your mail you need to change the following two lines as well to keep the fake sender:

```
maildoc.Principal = "LSBSAdmin@somedomain.com"  'principal
```

to

```
maildoc.From = "LSBSAdmin@somedomain.com@YOURNOTESDOMAIN"  'from
maildoc.Principal = "LSBSAdmin@somedomain.com@YOURNOTESDOMAIN"  'principal
```

Comment: if dint update the mailbox, it will not be able to show the user fake principal. If i change back the update mailbox, then it wouldn't save a copy of sent message out.

Comment: Sorry ,what i means is below coding 


replace

Set maildb = ss.getdatabase (db.server, "mail.box") 'Get Mailbox on server 
with

Set maildb = New NotesDatabase( "" , "" )
Call maildb.openMail()



It will not be able to change the fake sender

Comment: Did you read the last lines in my code? The second @ is essential for faking the sender!

Comment: i just updated my question and attached few image for description. Sorry dint point out problem correctly.

Comment: This is NOT a notesdomain that you add there but the internet domain. The notes domain does NOT have a dot in it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160063/discussion-between-desmond-sim-and-torsten-link).